# Is there a one line cmd to install wordpress locally with composer?

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, installation

Using laracasts I was able to install a new Laravel project by typing in `laravel new project-name` into the console and it will install a new Laravel install. 
I was looking to have the same functionality with WordPress. I found a few tutorials that mentioned that said to install WordPress with composer I would have to put a composer.json file in the folder I want to install WordPress in with

```
{   "require": {
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "*"   } }
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to set it up so I can just type in `wordpress new project-name` and composer will create a folder using that name with a blank WordPress install. I'm guessing maybe I would use an alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`laravel new project-name` is probably a shortcut for `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name`. It basically uses `laravel/laravel` package as a project template and initializes your app using it as a starter. If you want similar functionality for WordPress, you need to find project template for Wordpress. You may try [`Bedrock`](https://roots.io/bedrock/) as am example, but there are also other starters for WordPress:

```
composer create-project roots/bedrock project-name
```

If you really want to use `wordpress new` syntax, you should probably create custom `wordpress` command which will call `composer create-project` internally. But I would not recommend that, it does not give much benefits, just hides what is really happening.

Comment: Gotcha, I will check out Bedrock. Thanks!